# URL rewrite in magento2 config

Tags: magento2

How to URL rewrite the same in Magento2?

```
<!-- url rewrite -->
 <rewrite>
    <mypage>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/([\w-]+)/m/?#]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[/m/index/index/product/$1]]></to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </mypage>
</rewrite>
<!-- end url rewrite -->
<frontend>
<routers>
   <mypage>
      <use>standard</use>
        <args>
           <module>Vendor_Module</module>
           <frontName>m</frontName>
        </args>
   </mypage>
 </routers>
```

Where should i give this code in magento2

Here, when i hit the controller localhost/mypage/result/index... here im replacing mypage by 'm'

AS:  localhost/m/result/index

Comment: Can manage through `Admin -> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites`?

Comment: do you want to rewrite the controller or what its not clear please explain more ?

Comment: I have explained the detailed answer here.. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139412/optimize-magentos-controller-action-url @Ankit