# Optimize magentos controller action URL

Tags: magento2

How to cut short the URL of a controller action page in `magento2`

For instance:

If custom modules controller page is in : **Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php**

in `routes.xml`: I had defined frontname as : `i`

Instead of navigating to : **localhost/magento/i/index/index**

How to optimize the URl to only **localhost/magento/i**

Basically , i need to achieve this (as in magento1) in Magento2.

```
<!-- url rewrite -->
<rewrite>
<mypage>
    <from><![CDATA[#^/([\w-]+)/m/?#]]></from>
    <to><![CDATA[/m/index/index/product/$1]]></to>
    <complete>1</complete>
</mypage>
</rewrite>
<!-- end url rewrite -->
<frontend>
<routers>
<mypage>
  <use>standard</use>
    <args>
       <module>Vendor_Module</module>
       <frontName>m</frontName>
    </args>
  </mypage>
 </routers>
```

For the above rewrite : we can get the controller action just by:

localhost/magento/m

Need to achieve the same in Magento2 ?

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="m" frontName="m">
        <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

Controller path:  **\Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index.php**

layout file name: **m_result_index**

URL: localhost/magento/m

I get 404 no found.

Cleared cache and gen

Comment: May be need to go for custom routng https://www.smartiehastheanswer.co.uk/magento2/creating-a-custom-frontend-route-in-magento2.html / http://inchoo.net/magento-2/routing-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

Define frontName as `i` in `routes.xml`

Add file `i_index_index.xml` in `yourmodule/frontend/layout`

Now you can directly access `localhost/magento/i`

Comment: Please find the updated answer, i tried the above, i get 404

Comment: @SachinS I have tested from my side, it's working for me

Comment: with just localhost/magento/i from my code? is ur controller action loading?

Comment: Yes exactly localhost/mymagento2/myroute calls myroute/index/index

Comment: @SachinS Your frontName must be atleast tree character long

Comment: Could you brief pls, as u said Define frontName as i in routes.xml, whats tree character long?

Comment: Sorry, it was typo mistake, frontName must be atleast three character long, only 'i' will not work